# Can you cache the 'find' command?

Tags: linux, cache, find

I wrote a simple shell script which uses the 'find' command so non-technical users can do a search on the file server through a web browser on the LAN. It works, but sometimes it has a long execution time, and then the follow-up searches are quick.

Is there a way to force a cache for 'find' or perhaps run something in the CRON to do this daily or a few times a day so users don't have to wait so long to get their first results?

Answer (score 3):

The `locate` command is designed to do exactly what you want. The software package includes a (typically daily) cron job that creates a database of existing files, and then the `locate` command will use that database to search for files instead of crawling through the filesystem tree.

Your Linux distribution may even offer you several implementations of `locate`: in addition to the implementation included in GNU `findutils`, there may be newer implementations `slocate` and/or `mlocate`.

- Both `slocate` and `mlocate` will filter out any search results the user running the search would not be able to access, according to file and directory permissions.
- `mlocate` will also speed up database updates by detecting which directories have not changed after the previous database update.

Comment: So if I want to restrict locate to search for foobaz, this would work and won't be delayed by it collecting a cache?
locate -ir '^/home/share/\([^.][^/]\+/\)\+foobaz[^/]*$'

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @telcoM is probably the correct one you should follow. However, around ten years ago I once had no choice other than to keep the whole directory tree cached.

My solution back then was to put something like

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/find / 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

to my cron, so the directory tree was scanned very often and remained cached.